# Android fragment show/hide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am writing an app that the MainActivity contains multiple fragments, and I want some of the fragments hidden initially, so I do something like this:

```
    //Some class variables in MainActivity
    private F1 f1 = new F1();
    private F2 f2 = new F2();
    private F3 f3 = new F3();
    //some more variables...

    //onCreate in MainActivity
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, f1);
    ft.add(R.id.container, f2);
    ft.hide(f2);
    ft.add(R.id.container, f3);
    ft.hide(f3);
    ft.add(R.id.container, f4);
    ft.add(R.id.container, f5);
    ft.add(R.id.container, f6);
    ft.commit();

    //Methods in MainActivity
    public void showf2(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(f2).commit();
    }

    public void showf3(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(f3).commit();
    }

    //F2
    public class F2 extends Fragment{
    private LinearLayout view;
    private FrameLayout hContainer;
    private LinearLayout list;
    private TextView title;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private LinearLayout scrollViewInner;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            ));
            hContainer = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            list = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            title = new TextView(getActivity());
            scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
            scrollViewInner = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

            //...
            //some more code here

            list.addView(title);
            scrollView.addView(scrollViewInner);
            list.addView(scrollView);
            hContainer.addView(list);
            view.addView(hContainer);

            return view;
    }
```

The views of f2 and f3 are created dynamically, which means the views are generated using Java code instead of XML. I tested the layout individually and they displayed correctly, so you can assume the codes in f2 and f3 are correct.

The showf2() and showf3() are for showing the fragment again.
However, when I call these two methods, the fragments did not show at all. But if I add some static views in my fragments (using XML), those static views in f2 and f3 can show through calling showf2() and showf3().

So, can anyone explain why and spot the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the views? Since you are creating these views dynamically, are you adding them to the viewGroup or layout?

Comment: How did you implements the fragment class?
Have you implemented as Google guidelines?
Than the management of the lifecicle become more simple and clean.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I added some more codes in my question, since the codes are really long, I paste only part of them here.

And I have tried to comment out ft.hide(f2);, the fragment showed perfectly...